# setting up home folders for users for 12.04 server edition -ls: cannot open directory .: Permission denied

Tags: server, home-directory

I created an instance to run on a cloud service. The machine image was 12.04 server edition x64.

Upon initially logging in and creating a user and su'ing into that user it doesn't have a home folder:

```
root@chrisjlee:~# useradd -G www-data me
root@chrisjlee:~# su me
$ ls
ls: cannot open directory .: Permission denied
$ cd ~
sh: 2: cd: can't cd to /home/me
$
```

Do i have to initialize something in order for home folders to be automatically created?

Comment: useradd doesn't create the home folder. If you want to do that, you need to use adduser instead. http://linuxers.org/article/differences-between-useradd-and-adduser-commands

Comment: But on a desktop that's all setup for me when i create a user. Is that because the desktop version of ubuntu does that (Create a homefolder; set the permissions) for me?

Comment: In short, yes. The files are copied from /etc/skel/ and the permissions set properly.